# word-break: break-word not working in <select> element Internet explorer 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, select, word-break

word-break: break-word working fine in all the other browser including Internet Explorer.
But as soon as you add it into a `<SELECT></SELECT>` element.

Here is a sample that works in all browsers except IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style> 
      p.test, select
      {
        width:100px; 
        border:1px solid #000000;
        -ms-word-break: break-all; /* wraps the text in the selector so it prints properly*/
            word-break: break-all;
            /* Non standard for webkit */
            word-break: break-word;
       -webkit-hyphens: auto;
          -moz-hyphens: auto;
           -ms-hyphens: auto;
               hyphens: auto;
           white-space: pre-wrap;
        border: 1px dotted red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="test"> This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword. The long word will break and wrap to the next line.</p>
    <select class="test">
      <option>testshr1</option>
      <option>tb details</option>
      <option>This paragraph contains a very long word: thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylongword.</option>
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature in IE: it simply renders each `option` element on one line. Looking at the situation in Developer Tools, you can see that your settings are recognized (and inherited, when applicable, from `select` to `option`). But the rendering of a `select` element is special, and does not do line breaks.

The conclusion is that you should not create such problems. The `select` element is meant to be used for relatively short options, and the IE behavior is quite understandable. Either shorten the `option` texts considerably, or use a different control, like a set of radio buttons.

Comment: Hi the reason for the large select options are due to reporting options in my application. It would have been great if it worked in IE as well as Firefox and Chrome. There  must be some hack one of you CSS Guru's can suggest please.

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
<style>
select option{
            width:100px; 
            word-break: break-all;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Sarah, thanks for this suggestion. I gave it a shot and its not working.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
word-wrap: break-word
```